# Get the Name of a related record

Tags: apex, force.com

I have custom object and custom object field which is a lookup to Account. I am able to retrieve account record value from the lookup field but I am getting only the id of the record . I need to get the name of the record.

for eg: The record name is 'Ac_record' and the ID is '123456609xya', I am only getting the id not the name of the Account record.

How can I achieve it?

my code:

```
 obj = select id, name, Location__c from customObj__c where id in: setId;
 srting location = obj.Location__c;
```

`location__c` is lookup to Account, please help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use

```
obj = select id, name, Location__r.name from customObj__c where id in: setId;
```